# Not able to post data through wp-admin

Tags: posts, capabilities

I have a wordpress site wordpress version is "3.8.26". My php version is 7.

when am adding new post to my site its not displaying "publish button" its showing "Submit for review". button [image]

And categories also not displaying in the wp-admin page right side.

Anybody could you please help me to resolve the issue.

[image]

Thank you.

if i submit for review button it will display

[image]

Comment: Which post type you are looking? Is it default page, post or something custom post type?

Comment: I have a category , I want to post related to the category.

Comment: Hi Baikare Sandeep I have attache a snapshot. while adding a post via wp-admin its showing submit for a review. my wordpress version is old. but am using latest php version (7). I dont know what to do next. the right side category also not displaying .

Comment: this doesn't look like WordPress 3.8, would that rather be 4.8 ?

Comment: your saying from our side need to update the wordpress?

Comment: I think you are not logged with administrator role

Comment: I checked in my data base "wp_usermeta" - table , in the table its showing wp_user_level is 10 for the corresponding user id.

Comment: Do you have migrated the database from another wordpress installation? If it's really an autoincrement problem, you could use a db tool (e.g. phpMyAdmin) to set the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. I haven't tested this, so please make a database backup before and use a testsystem. Open your database, select a table (e.g. {tableprefix}_posts), click the Structure tab and edit the ID column. There you can enable/disable the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute for this column. Another approach is to export the hole database with the Add AUTO_INCREMENT value selected, delete and re-import the database.

Comment: Maybe its the problem with data base in my localhost am using "Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution"

and the hosting server am using "Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)"

is there any dependency is there ?

all code should execute both versions right ?

any issue will come the above scenario?

Comment: This same project is working fine in "Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.16 - Source distribution"  and development server "Server type: MariaDB Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution"

the above scenario i didn't see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try by debugging the code, might be there is an issue because of a New version of PHP. 
Try by writing this code into the `wp-config.php` file and see what if any error:

```
 // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

NOTE: You must insert this BEFORE /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ in the wp-config.php file

Comment: I tried with the above mentioned suggestion. It's not displaying error /warning.

Comment: But the same project working fine in PHP 5 version . Am not changed anything. Just I moved the same project to PHP 7 server. I thought everything will work there.

Comment: Make sure you have updated both constants true `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true ); @ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); ` , and see once or see on this location for log file: `/wp-content/debug.log`